# python-quickcheck: error fixture not found

Tags: python, pytest, quickcheck

I'm trying to use the `python-quickcheck` library, and I just wrote a super simple test inspired by the official documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytest


@pytest.mark.randomize(min_num=0, max_num=2, ncalls=5)
def test_generate_int_anns(i1: int):
    assert i1 == i1
```

However, when I run the tests with `pytest -v test_debug.py`, I get errors:

```
E       fixture 'i1' not found
```

Also, when I use the `--randomize` parameter, the test is just skipped... What is the issue?

PS: Here is a full log:

```
[nix-shell:/tmp/debug]$ pytest -v test_debug.py
============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /nix/store/bs03sg8b0gq2zr4v252hh9psp780qj5q-python3-3.8.5/bin/python3.8
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/debug
plugins: quickcheck-0.8.4
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test_debug.py::test_generate_int_anns ERROR                                                                                                                                                                [100%]

===================================================================================================== ERRORS =====================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_generate_int_anns ____________________________________________________________________________________
file /tmp/debug/test_debug.py, line 5
  @pytest.mark.randomize(min_num=0, max_num=2, ncalls=5)
  def test_generate_int_anns(i1: int):
E       fixture 'i1' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

/tmp/debug/test_debug.py:5
============================================================================================ short test summary info =============================================================================================
ERROR test_debug.py::test_generate_int_anns
=====================================


[nix-shell:/tmp/debug]$ pytest -v --randomize test_debug.py
============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /nix/store/bs03sg8b0gq2zr4v252hh9psp780qj5q-python3-3.8.5/bin/python3.8
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/debug
plugins: quickcheck-0.8.4
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test_debug.py::test_generate_int_anns SKIPPED                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

=============================================================================================== 1 skipped in 0.02s ===============================================================================================
```

-- EDIT --
As asked in the comments, here is the output of the recommended command:

```
$ pytest --fixtures .
============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /tmp/debug
plugins: quickcheck-0.8.4
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                                                                                
cache
    Return a cache object that can persist state between testing sessions.
    
    cache.get(key, default)
    cache.set(key, value)
    
    Keys must be a ``/`` separated value, where the first part is usually the
    name of your plugin or application to avoid clashes with other cache users.
    
    Values can be any object handled by the json stdlib module.

capsys
    Enable text capturing of writes to ``sys.stdout`` and ``sys.stderr``.
    
    The captured output is made available via ``capsys.readouterr()`` method
    calls, which return a ``(out, err)`` namedtuple.
    ``out`` and ``err`` will be ``text`` objects.

capsysbinary
    Enable bytes capturing of writes to ``sys.stdout`` and ``sys.stderr``.
    
    The captured output is made available via ``capsysbinary.readouterr()``
    method calls, which return a ``(out, err)`` namedtuple.
    ``out`` and ``err`` will be ``bytes`` objects.

capfd
    Enable text capturing of writes to file descriptors ``1`` and ``2``.
    
    The captured output is made available via ``capfd.readouterr()`` method
    calls, which return a ``(out, err)`` namedtuple.
    ``out`` and ``err`` will be ``text`` objects.

capfdbinary
    Enable bytes capturing of writes to file descriptors ``1`` and ``2``.
    
    The captured output is made available via ``capfd.readouterr()`` method
    calls, which return a ``(out, err)`` namedtuple.
    ``out`` and ``err`` will be ``byte`` objects.

doctest_namespace [session scope]
    Fixture that returns a :py:class:`dict` that will be injected into the namespace of doctests.

pytestconfig [session scope]
    Session-scoped fixture that returns the :class:`_pytest.config.Config` object.
    
    Example::
    
        def test_foo(pytestconfig):
            if pytestconfig.getoption("verbose") > 0:
                ...

record_property
    Add an extra properties the calling test.
    User properties become part of the test report and are available to the
    configured reporters, like JUnit XML.
    The fixture is callable with ``(name, value)``, with value being automatically
    xml-encoded.
    
    Example::
    
        def test_function(record_property):
            record_property("example_key", 1)

record_xml_attribute
    Add extra xml attributes to the tag for the calling test.
    The fixture is callable with ``(name, value)``, with value being
    automatically xml-encoded

record_testsuite_property [session scope]
    Records a new ``<property>`` tag as child of the root ``<testsuite>``. This is suitable to
    writing global information regarding the entire test suite, and is compatible with ``xunit2`` JUnit family.
    
    This is a ``session``-scoped fixture which is called with ``(name, value)``. Example:
    
    .. code-block:: python
    
        def test_foo(record_testsuite_property):
            record_testsuite_property("ARCH", "PPC")
            record_testsuite_property("STORAGE_TYPE", "CEPH")
    
    ``name`` must be a string, ``value`` will be converted to a string and properly xml-escaped.

caplog
    Access and control log capturing.
    
    Captured logs are available through the following properties/methods::
    
    * caplog.messages        -> list of format-interpolated log messages
    * caplog.text            -> string containing formatted log output
    * caplog.records         -> list of logging.LogRecord instances
    * caplog.record_tuples   -> list of (logger_name, level, message) tuples
    * caplog.clear()         -> clear captured records and formatted log output string

monkeypatch
    The returned ``monkeypatch`` fixture provides these
    helper methods to modify objects, dictionaries or os.environ::
    
        monkeypatch.setattr(obj, name, value, raising=True)
        monkeypatch.delattr(obj, name, raising=True)
        monkeypatch.setitem(mapping, name, value)
        monkeypatch.delitem(obj, name, raising=True)
        monkeypatch.setenv(name, value, prepend=False)
        monkeypatch.delenv(name, raising=True)
        monkeypatch.syspath_prepend(path)
        monkeypatch.chdir(path)
    
    All modifications will be undone after the requesting
    test function or fixture has finished. The ``raising``
    parameter determines if a KeyError or AttributeError
    will be raised if the set/deletion operation has no target.

recwarn
    Return a :class:`WarningsRecorder` instance that records all warnings emitted by test functions.
    
    See http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html for information
    on warning categories.

tmpdir_factory [session scope]
    Return a :class:`_pytest.tmpdir.TempdirFactory` instance for the test session.
        

tmp_path_factory [session scope]
    Return a :class:`_pytest.tmpdir.TempPathFactory` instance for the test session.
        

tmpdir
    Return a temporary directory path object
    which is unique to each test function invocation,
    created as a sub directory of the base temporary
    directory.  The returned object is a `py.path.local`_
    path object.
    
    .. _`py.path.local`: https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html

tmp_path
    Return a temporary directory path object
    which is unique to each test function invocation,
    created as a sub directory of the base temporary
    directory.  The returned object is a :class:`pathlib.Path`
    object.
    
    .. note::
    
        in python < 3.6 this is a pathlib2.Path
```

Comment: try to follow the error text: `use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.` and post here the output

Comment: @zvi I don't find this command really helping... but see my edit.

Comment: Also, it seems to be a known bug... But can't see how this library is useful with that bug: https://github.com/t2y/pytest-quickcheck/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug in 0.8.5. Try again with the latest version.
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-quickcheck/0.8.5/